# Speed On a Road Bike

Tags: road-bike, speed

My old (But freakin' awesome) french road bike goes fast, considering that the only times im racing is pretty much against my friends who all have mountain bikes. Needless to say I always win. But I would like even faster speed. I understand that IM the engine, and I need to be fit, but would upgrading to a newer and lighter road bike gain me any noticeable improvements in speed?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Agreed. What is being asked? Have you looked for all of the other relevant questions?

Comment: I think the question is "Are you as awesome as me and my bike?"

Comment: A road bike outperforms mountain bikes on roads.  Imagine that. Try racing your friends on mountain trails and report back how it works out.

Answer (score 2):

The question is "would upgrading to a newer and lighter road bike gain me any noticeable improvements in speed?".

The answer is a loud YES!!

The doubt remains regarding "is it worth the extra money?" and that's difficult to answer. If you have a lot of money, or really want extra performance (for a given fitness level) and don't mind throwing the money, you'll most probably get back this money in the form of a lighter, faster bike.

But I have to say: sometimes one spends a lot more money and get back not so much extra speed.

(of course I'm talking of AVERAGE speed during dozens of miles, not isolated bursts of maximum speed).

What I think you should do, before anything else, is to FIND OUT A GROUP OF ROAD RIDERS to go along. I understand you want more speed, and you won't get the challenge from a MTB group, if you ride a road bike.

With a group of roadies, you'll not only find out how it is to ride along a faster pack, but also will see a lot of different road bikes. Most probably you'll notice that not always the faster rides have the lighter or more expensive bikes.

Hope this helps!